# How can I add variables into a dictionary with a loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary, python-3.4

I'm pretty new to python and I'm trying to create loops that are capable of doing all the work that I did by hand. Essentially creating all the **line'#'** variables and assigning them the particular line of text from the file *'game_catch.txt'* which reads something like this:

```
Curving                 10
Dodgeball               15
Keep Away               5
Kin-Ball                7
Prisoner Ball           21
Quidditch               30
Rundown (aka Pickle)    12
Yukigassen              18
Handball                25
```

(With the spaces being Tabs, if that makes any difference)

Then creating another loop that assigns the value of the **line'#'** variables to **str'#'** variables while splitting all the spacing away. (I cannot modify the file because in other computers it will be the same as the one I posted above, so I have to do this step)

Then, and more importantly because this is where I'm completely stuck, making a loop for doing all the nitty gritty work of turning the **str'#'** variables into something the sports dictionary can pick up and then read as **{'Curving': 10}**

Here I provided the code I'm currently using and trying to simplify:

```
file = open('game_catch.txt','r')
line1 = file.readline()
line2 = file.readline()
line3 = file.readline()
line4 = file.readline()
line5 = file.readline()
line6 = file.readline()
line7 = file.readline()
line8 = file.readline()
line9 = file.readline()

str1 = line1.split()
str2 = line2.split()
str3 = line3.split()
str4 = line4.split()
str5 = line5.split()
str6 = line6.split()
str7 = line7.split()
str8 = line8.split()
str9 = line9.split()

sports = {}

key = ''
for i in str1[0:-1] :
    key += i + ' '

key = key[0:-1]

sports[key] = int(str1[-1])
```

Sorry for the long post, I just wanted to provide as much detail as possible. Feel free to let me know if there are more efficient ways of doing this. Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html), specifically the section on [control flow](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: Can you provide an example of whats in the txt file so we can copy and paste it to test?

Comment: Why do you need all lines to be read into separate variables?

Comment: And I don't know where you picked up the habit of doing `sequence[0:-1]`, but it doesn't do what you probably think it does. Also read about [the `str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: You will find it much, much easier to program in Python if you first learn some basics. Even an online tutorial like the official one I linked above would be a great start.

Comment: @Tiger Thanks for the feedback and tips. I'm barely learning the basics so I've picked up (probably some bad habits) from other questions/solutions I've found across the internet.

Comment: @PeterWood I guess I do not need to do that. But with my basic knowledge I figured that would be convenient. Which is probably not the case.

Comment: @Simon [Text Example](http://pastebin.com/n2qXp48E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will turn you txt file into a dictionary, taking into consideration that some of the sports names are comprised of multiple words:

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n').split() for line in open('C:/Users/Simon/Desktop/test.txt')]

sports = {}

for el in lines:
    number = el.pop()
    curItem = ' '.join(el)

    sports[curItem] = int(number)

print sports
```

That will give something like this:

```
{'Curving': 10, 'Keep Away': 5, 'Dodgeball': 15}
```

Comment: Good catch on the multi-word names; I didn't read the entire sample input and missed it. I'd suggest `sports[curItem] = int(number)` to get an integer value as requested.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a basic structure (which will keep the scores as strings) by iterating over the file, splitting each line, and sending the pairs in that generator to `dict()`:

```
with open('game_catch.txt') as f:
    d = dict(line.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for line in f)
```

You can cast the scores as integers by creating a generator to split each line, then unpacking each line and using the `int()` function:

```
with open('game_catch.txt') as f:
    d = dict((name, int(score)) for name, score in (line.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for line in f))
```

You can use the literal comprehension syntax instead of the `dict()` function:

```
with open('game_catch.txt') as f:
    d = {name:int(score) for name, score in (line.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for line in f)}
```

The most important part is, of course, to check out a tutorial so that you can understand what these code snippets are doing and make sense of the explanations. Loops and data structures are particularly important.

Comment: I like the use of the generator. I usually create a single element list to iterate over so I can do processing and get named variables. The generator's a lot neater.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = 'game_catch.txt'
sports = {}

with open(file) as f:
 for line in f:
  parts = line.split()
  sports[parts[0]] = int(parts[-1])
```

hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need `lines = f.readlines()`, by the way - just do `for line in f:` and put that part inside the `with` block.